# Moving an Object on a circular path in Java

Tags: java, java-2d

I want to make a Solar System kind of Simulator an therefor I want to move a Planet around the Sun.
I got the drawing Part done, but I don't know how to do the circular moving Part around the sun.

Thank you.

Comment: You should really post some code. Also, make sure you show us your own attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have the **coordinates** of the sun and the desired **radius**, like

```
double sunX = ...
double sunY = ...

double radius = ...
```

and some kind of **game-time** which we use to determine current position together with some kind of **speed**:

```
int time = ...
```

Let's say the time increases **once per millisecond**. And the planet should start movement from `0°`  and reach `360°` (from `0` to `2 * PI`) again after `2` seconds (`2000` milliseconds), then the **current angle** may be determined by

```
double orbitalPeriod = 2000.0;
double portion = (time % orbitalPeriod) / orbitalPeriod; // [0, 1)
double angle = portion * 2 * Math.PI;                    // [0, 2 * PI)
```

We can now easily compute the coordinates for the planet by using the desired *angle* and *radius*.

```
double planetX = sunX + radius * Math.cos(angle);
double planetY = sunY + radius * Math.sin(angle);
```

You can read more about the formula on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations). The following image might probably help in understanding the equation:

[image]